How can I force plots to be the same size when the figsize setting does nothing in pyplot?
I wrote the following code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

symetricArr=[[random.random() for i in range(100)] for j in range(100)]
asymetricArr=[[random.random() for i in range(50)] for j in range(100)]

plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))

plt.imshow(symetricArr, cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')

plt.show()

plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))

plt.imshow(asymetricArr, cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')

plt.show()

Which should produce two figures that are the exact same size but the figsize property does not take for some reason.  Instead it produces this:

How can I make this produce two plots that are the exact same size?

You're not searching for figsize, you're searching for how to scale an axis of an imshow

@TinoD yes aspect='auto' did the trick.  Thanks!
